# Add method and while loop do not execute properly

Tags: java

This program is a contact book. There is a contact class and contact book class. When I execute case 2, the add method from the contact book class does not let me enter name and phone number individually. "Enter a name" and "Enter an address" appear at the same time.

Here is the switch case in the main method:

```
    while (!done)
     {  
        ContactBook cb = new ContactBook();
        System.out.println("1) List all contacts" + "\n" + "2) Add a contact"
         + "\n" + "3) Update a contact" + "\n" + "4) Remove a contact" +
         "\n" + "5) Quit");
        userChoice = sc.nextInt();

        switch (userChoice)
        {
            case 1:
                c.toString();
                break;

            case 2:
                cb.add(sc);
                break;

            case 3:
                cb.update(sc);
                break;

            case 4:
                cb.remove(sc);

        }
        if (userChoice == 5);
        {
            done = true;
        }
     }


}
```

Here is the add method from the contact book class:

```
public void add (Scanner sc)
{
    Contact c = new Contact(name, address, phone, email);
    System.out.println("Enter a name: ");
    c.setName(sc.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Enter an address: ");
    c.setAddress(sc.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Enter a phone number: ");
    c.setPhone(sc.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Enter an email: ");
    c.setEmail(sc.nextLine());
    entries = Arrays.copyOf(entries, entries.length + 1);
}
```

Comment: `nextInt` doesnt consume new line from the input, you need to fire blank sc.nextLine() after the `nextInt()`. While using scanner make sure you flush the buffer for new line.

Comment: The next time, read and try this first: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I did all I could before I asked the question.  The question is pretty specific and only includes parts of my program needed. I would like to thank you for you answer it was very useful. I was stuck and have been searching through books and tracing my program line by line which is why I turned to stack to get a human perspective :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the following:

```
userChoice = sc.nextInt();
```

to

```
userChoice = Integer.valueOf(sc.nextLine());
```

Comment: Good anwser Sir!

Answer (score 0):

I think this should fix your problem

```
System.out.print("Enter a name: ");
c.setName(sc.nextLine());
System.out.println()
```